# Robovm libGDX project on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus simulators (xcode 6)

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, ios8, robovm

Is it possible to run `RoboVM` app on iphone 6 / 6 plus simulator?

I am using eclipse with the latest `RoboVM` (not the nightlies) with XCode 6. It is working fine on iPhone 5 with iOS 8.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse, Click Run --> Run Configurations --> iOS Simulator App, then choose your Project and change the device to the type you want (iPhone 4, 5, 6, etc)

[image]

[image]